# Blackberry Playbook WebWorks Debugging: Log Files? Debugging Messages?

Tags: debugging, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-playbook

I'm trying to debug a WebWorks application using the Blackberry Playbook simulator (not Ripple, the VMWare simulator). Something is causing a problem and my javascript is just failing to execute after a certain point, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Is there a log file where errors are recorded?

If not, is there a way I can view system error messages (or something like that) to help me determine at runtime what kinds of problems I need to fix?

Answer (score 0):

See [Debugging BlackBerry web applications using Web Inspector](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/06/debugging-blackberry-web-apps/) and try out the remote Web Inspector tool that is part of WebKit.  The BlackBerry PlayBook was the first device to ship with this feature of WebKit.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working, but having a hell of a time. When I deploy to my testing device the app crashes on start up. I'm still trying to get it running in the vmware simulator. I'll update when I get it running.